# magento add js function call to input with php

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I'm tryin to make some changes on the advanced search of magento. I'd like to make the inputs appear one by one. so I need to put a  `onchange='showNext()'` in every input, but the inputs are generated by PHP like this :

```
return $this -> _getSelectBlock() -> setName($name) -> setId($attribute 
->getAttributeCode()) -> setTitle($this -> getAttributeLabel($attribute)) 
-> setExtraParams("") -> setValue($this -> getAttributeValue($attribute))
-> setOptions($options) -> getHtml();
```

thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return $this -> _getSelectBlock() -> setName($name) -> setId($attribute 
->getAttributeCode()) -> setTitle($this -> getAttributeLabel($attribute)) 
-> setExtraParams("onchange=\'showNext()\'") -> setValue($this -> getAttributeValue($attribute))
-> setOptions($options) -> getHtml();
```

Comment: no , it doesn't work with  :
-> setExtraParams("onchange=\'showNext()\'")

Comment: try setOnchange() it might just iterate over all data that is set to it